# How to get reference to ActiveRecord child from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following Models...

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

And given the following queries...

```
child = Child.first
parent = child.parent
```

**Is it possible to get a reference to `child` from within an instance method of `parent`?**

Comment: if you eager_load/include while querying parent you can get instance

Comment: parent has_many child, so somewhere you have to specify which child is required. I don't know the details, so it's hard to tell what the best solution is, but for example in an instance method you either pass in the child or search for it from within the method. parent.any_method(child_id) would be the former and parent.child.where(sth: sth) would be the latter.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was curious if doing as you're suggesting @SzilardMagyar was redundant in someway, if the child_id was already present in the relationship behind the scenes.

Comment: Depends on the business logic.

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is `child.parent.any_method` without the `child_id`, as you suggested. It may not be possible.